# webrtcjingle disconnect crash on ios Lukeweber version

Tags: ios, webrtc

I just downloaded the lukeweber version of webrtcjingle, which I believe is just a branch of the google one. 
I change the server and account setting on the demo and run it. It was able to log in and send/receive messages. However, When I tried to logout. The app crash.

I had a little debug on it, and found out the line of code that crash was in file txmppump.cc, function:

`void TXmppPump::WakeTasks() {
      talk_base::Thread::Current()->Post(this);
    }`

Does anyone have an idea what the problem is? I noticed that there is a fix on disconnecting problem issued caused by a race problem on the repo:
[github bug list](https://github.com/lukeweber/webrtc-jingle-client/commit/f59951677314a01848215d8d7dcc2b9647239cd3)

However, I compared my code to the fixed version. They are the same. So I dont know if they are related or not.